# In the pilot episode of Rick and Morty, how does Rick get through customs without getting caught?

Tags: rick-and-morty

In the pilot episode of Rick and Morty, Rick's portal gun fails, so they need to take the interdimensional customs.

Since Rick is a wanted criminal, how does he almost make it through customs without getting caught? Remember, they only got caught due to the random anal checking, not due to Rick's recognizance.

[image]

Even if the customs agent didn't recognize him, Rick should have been scared to go through the customs process.

Comment: why should he be scared? in the beginning he did mention that he has gone through the customs by shoving the seeds *way up his butt* several times.

Comment: @Shreedhar "Why should he be scared?"?!!? You obviously haven't watched the full show, but basic canon is that rick and the Galactic Federation don't get along. And that's putting it mildly.

Comment: I have watched Rick and Morty. and yeah i know about Rick's history with the GF. but nowhere is it mentioned that Rick  is actually scared of the federation. Is it?